# Как подключить на сайт ASP Net MVC Websocket?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket

Я использовал `WebSocketSharp` в консольном приложении для создания Websocket соединения.
Как настроить Websocket соединение в приложении ASP Net MVC ?(желательно не используя SignalR, так как архитектуру я хочу построить сам, а там много не нужного).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я создал папку WebSocketServer с проектом (на библиотеке `WebSocketSharp`) и просто в global.asax создал экземпляр сервера при запуске самого веб сервера и всё гуд.